# How to add date-picker to content editable td?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Following is my code:

```js
var j = jQuery.noConflict();
j(".datetimepicker").click(function() {
  j(".datetimepicker").datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
    onClose: function(dateText, inst) {
      // When the date is selected, copy the value in the content editable div.
      // If you don't need to do anything on the blur or focus event of the content editable div, you don't need to trigger them as I do in the line below.
      $(this).parent().find('.datetimepicker').focus().html(dateText).blur();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<tr>
  <th>First Date</th>
  <td class='datetimepicker' contenteditable='true'>"+ paidDate1 + "</td>
</tr>
```

So when I clicked on that row, the content is editable but the date-picker is not showing up. How can I fix this?

Comment: Jquery Datepicket can only be added to input box. 

You cannot add it to block elements like td , div, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK You cannot use `datepicker` with `<td>`, so there's a way to do by replacing the content with `<input>`.

If that's not what you want, please forgive me.

```js
var newDate = new Date();
var paidDate1 = newDate.getFullYear() + "/" + ('0' + (newDate.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + "/" + ('0' + newDate.getDay()).slice(-2);

var tr = "<tr><th>First Date</th><td>" + paidDate1 + "</td></tr>";

$('#t').append(tr);

// to avoid twice click on td;
$("#t").on('click.input', 'input', function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
})

$("#t").on('click.td', 'td', function() {
    var $td = $(this);
    var text = $(this).html();
    var $input = $('<input class="datetimepicker" value="' + text + '"/>');
    $td.html('').append($input);

    $input.datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
        onClose: function(dateText, inst) {
            $td.html(dateText.split('-').reverse().join('/'));
            $td.attr('disabled', false);
        }
    }).datepicker('show');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<table id="t"></table>
```

Answer (score -3):

Have you try tu use `j(document).find('td.datetimepicker')`? The tables have strange behavior when you tri to select only by class.

Comment: It look like a comment.